# How to send authorization header in android using volley library GET method

Tags: android, json, android-volley

how to send Authorization header using volley library in android for GET method please help me thank you

```
  public void token(){
    SharedPreferences usuario = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(DataManager.SharedPreferences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String id = usuario.getString(DataManager.json_Id, "");
    final String token = usuario.getString(DataManager.json_Token,"");
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlReadUser, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if (!response.equals(null)) {
                Log.e("Your Array Response", response);
            } else {
                Log.e("Your Array Response", "Data Null");
            }
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            try {
                String responseBody = new String(volleyError.networkResponse.data, "utf-8");
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseBody);
                //loadingData.dismiss();
                if (jsonObject.getInt(DataManager.json_Code) == 400) {
                   // onDialogErrorResponse();
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                //Handle a malformed json response
                Log.d("Response", String.valueOf(e));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException error) {

                Log.d("Response", String.valueOf(error));
            }
        }
    }) {

        //This is for Headers If You Needed
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("TOKEN", token);
            return params;
        }
    };
    request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            10000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    requestQueue.add(request);
    DiskBasedCache cache = new 
    DiskBasedCache(getActivity().getCacheDir(), 500 * 1024 * 1024);
    requestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, new BasicNetwork(new 
    HurlStack()));
    requestQueue.start();
}
```

I am trying to make the request to the server to bring data by the GET method, I have to send the Token so that I input but it returns an error where it tells me that the way to insert the header token is wrong, I hope they can support me.

Answer (score 2):

Authorization header generally sent as

```
params.put("Authorization", "bearer " +token);
```

Here bearer is auth type, it can be Basic as well as per your api's requirement.